# "Hide" an Active Directory domain in an open network

Tags: windows, active-directory, workgroup

I would like to have a stand-alone Active Directory deployment within an open network in a way that it isn't visible as a logon option or a workgroup to other, non-joined computers.  The plan so far was to:

1. Spin up server #1, make it a PDC
2. spin up server #2, set its DNS to PDC, join
   domain
3. hide it somehow
4. profit!

What should be disabled so that the domain joined servers don't advertise their AD/Workgroup?

Answer (score 2):

1. PDC/BDC lingo went away with the advent of Active Directory. What you have are domain controllers.
2. What makes you think that AD is in any way "advertised" on a network?
3. Even if it were "advertised", what difference does it make? One cannot join a computer to a domain without valid AD credentials.

If you want to "hide" anything on a network, you need to put a firewall between whatever it is that you're hiding and whom you're hiding it from. So - move your AD servers onto their own subnet and VLAN and then institute firewall rules to only allow that traffic which you require.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
AD is advertised because the workgroup and logon server for it is advertised and may appear in other computer list of domains to log on to.
My objective is to make sure that it doesn't appear neither in workgroup list nor in the logon list.
Finally, my note on open network - I am aware that if I would firewall them off noone would know, but that's not what I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, that's not how AD works. AD domains do not magically appear on clients for them to use.

Comment: `AD is advertised because the workgroup and logon server for it is advertised and may appear in other computer list of domains to log on to` - AD DS isn't "advertised". A client that isn't joined to a domain does not see any domains in the log onto drop down.

Answer (score 1):

So I wasn't going to answer this but I decided to post an answer to clear up a few things.

It **is** technically correct that a Domain Controller will broadcast NetBIOS Name Service traffic to the network broadcast address advertising itself as a Domain Controller for it's domain, but this in no way has any bearing on what computers "see" or have available to them when a user is logging on. A computer that is not joined to a domain will not "see" any domains available when a user logs on. A computer that is joined to a domain will only "see" the domain to which it is joined, or any domains trusted by it's own domain.

You might "see" other domains and workgroups in Network Neighborhood/My Network Places but those domains aren't "advertised" to computers as potential "targets" to log onto. A computer can only "see" and logon to a domain of which it is a member (or a domain trusted by it's own domain).

Maybe what you're really after is how to disable Network discovery so that computer(s) aren't visible in the network. If so, have a read here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-disable-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7